# Инициализация значений UNION в MASM32

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

Есть код:

```
X STRUC
    UNION
    STRUC A1
        BYTE ?
        BYTE ?
        BYTE ?
    ENDS
    STRUC A2
        WORD ?
        WORD ?
        WORD ?
    ENDS
    STRUC A3
        DWORD ?
        DWORD ?
        DWORD ?
    ENDS
    ENDS
X ENDS
```

Как мне задать переменную с проинициализированными значениями?
Если я напишу вот так:

```
Z X <{<1,2,3>}>
```

То получу 3 элемента типа BYTE (из структуры A1).
А если я хочу, чтобы это были не байты, а DWORD'ы (т.е. проинициализировать значения структуры A3), как мне это записать?

В TASM можно записать так:

```
X STRUC
    UNION
    STRUC
        DB ?
        DB ?
        DB ?
    ENDS
    STRUC
        DW ?
        DW ?
        DW ?
    ENDS
    STRUC
        DD ?
        DD ?
        DD ?
    ENDS
    ENDS
X ENDS

Z X <<?,?,<1,2,3>>>
```

А вот в MASM32 так не прокатит. Как же тогда???

Comment: ЕМНИП, в MASM можно инициализировать только первый элемент union. То есть в вашем случае просто поменять структуры местами. Но это надо уточнить в документации (собственно, разве там этого нет?)

Comment: В документации много всего понаписано, но конкретно об этом я нашёл только "For unions, the type of the initializer must be the same as the type for the first field." :(
http://people.sju.edu/~ggrevera/arch/references/MASM61PROGUIDE.pdf

Comment: Ну так это оно и есть. Если первой поставить структуру с `dd`, то `Z X <<1,2,3>>` или как-то так (ни masm, ни виндов в хозяйстве давно не водится чтобы проверить).